# Scala nested case statement cannot infer types and gives compiler error

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

In the following statement, Intellij complains regarding `aSub` (first red squiggly):

```
type mismatch: expected: Nothing, actual: Any
```

as well as a few other compiler squiggly red lines:

[image]

The IO type is defined as such:

```
  sealed trait IO[A] {
    def flatMap[B](f: A => IO[B]): IO[B] =
      FlatMap(this, f) // we do not interpret the `flatMap` here, just return it as a value
    def map[B](f: A => B): IO[B] =
      flatMap(f andThen (Return(_)))
  }
  case class Return[A](a: A) extends IO[A]
  case class Suspend[A](resume: () => A) extends IO[A]
  case class FlatMap[A,B](sub: IO[A], k: A => IO[B]) extends IO[B]
```

The interesting thing is that the Scala compiler in SBT does not complain about these types when run (`sbt compile`).

I am aware that Intellij has yet to catch up with `scalac`'s capability so I was hoping:

> **Are there explicit types I could give the variables to *"help"* Intellij with inference?**

---

### Update:

following the advice of @Doc, I have refactored the code with type parameters and still encounter the following:

[image]

Comment: `aSub : B` (where `B` is a type out of scope) and `f : B => IO[A]`. It looks like IntelliJ is assuming that `aSub`'s `B` is `Any` but `f`'s `B`, as an input, is `Nothing`. My guess would be to add type params to the first `case FlatMap`, and if the compiler complains than just put `@unchecked`

Comment: @Doc see the update. how would I add `@unchecked` to this? am I on the right track?

Comment: I don't think you need `@unchecked` unless scala gives you a type erasure warning. It looks like now IntelliJ is messing up similarly on the inner `case FlatMap`: `subsub : IO[C]` is being treated like `IO[Any]`, while `g : (C => IO[B])` retains at least its input type. Maybe remove the `C` type param from `step` and explicit types for `subsub` and `g`, and make another function `step2` for the inner `case FlatMap` which is like `step` for the outer one

Comment: I've raised an issue in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-10635